# Difficulties using UNIX cURL to scrape Ajax Wicket Information

Tags: ajax, curl, web-scraping, wicket, scrape

I am instructed to use write UNIX shell scripts that scrape certain websites. We use **fiddler** to trace the HTTP requests, then we write the **cURLs** accordingly. For the most part, scraping most websites seem to be fairly simple, however I've ran into a situation where I'm having difficulties capturing certain information.

I need to be somewhat generic in saying that I **cannot** provide the website address that I am actually looking at, however I can post some of the requests and responses to provide **context**.

Here's the situation:

The website starts with a search screen. You enter your search query and the website returns a list of results.

I need to choose the first result from the result page.

I need to capture **EVERYTHING** on the page from the first result.

***Everything up until this point is working fine***
Here's the problem:

The page returned has hyperlinks that are **wickets**. When these links are pressed, a window pops up within the page - it is not actually a window like a pop up created by javascript, it is more comparable to what you see when you 'compose a message' or 'poke' someone on Facebook ( am I the only one who still does that? ).

I need to capture the contents of that pop up window. There are usually **multiple** wicket links on a given page. Handling that should be easy enough with a loop, but I need to figure out the proper way to cURL those wickets first.

Here is the cURL i'm currently using to attempt to scrape the wickets.

(I'm explicitly defining the referrer URL, Accept, and Wicket-Ajax boolean as these were the items that were sent in the header when I traced the site). Link is the URL which looks like this:

http://www.someDomainName.com/searches/?x=as56f1sa65df1&random=0.121345151

( the random I believe is populated with some javascript, not sure if that's needed or even possible to recreate. I'm currently sending one of the randoms that I received on one particular occasion. ).

/bin/curl -v3 -b COOKIE -c COOKIE -H "Accept: text/xml" -H "Referer: $URL$x" -H "Wicket-Ajax: true" -sLf "$link"

Here is the response I get:

```
<ajax-response><redirect><![CDATA[home.page;jsessionid=6F45DF769D527B98DD1C7FFF3A0DF089]]></redirect>
</ajax-response>
```

I am expecting an XML document with actual content to be returned. Any insight into this issue would be greatly appreciated. Please let me know if you need more information.

Thanks,
Paul

Comment: It looks like the response tells javascript to set a cookie and redirect to home.page - Unix shell is definitely the wrong tool for this job.